Can I make an OLAP statement inside of a CASE statement in the Where clause work, or at least mimic the workflow?
I have researched and am finding that is "impossible" to do an OLAP statement inside a Case statement that is in the Where Clause, sample attached.  I find hard to believe that it cannot be mimicked somehow.
My goal is to have the query only return anything greater than 2 from my OLAP statement.  I was able to accomplish this with a CTE, but I was wondering if there might be another way.  Any and all help, suggestions, directions, references appreciated:
WHERE
1 = CASE
WHEN TO_CHAR(MAX((elh.end_effective_dt_tm - e.reg_dt_tm) * 24) OVER(PARTITION BY e.encntr_id), '9999.9') > 2 THEN 1
ELSE 0
END


You cannot use an aggregation function in the WHERE clause because that functionality is not supported. (If you want to know why, ask Oracle; we would just be speculating).
SELECT *
FROM   DUAL
WHERE  MAX(dummy) OVER(PARTITION BY dummy) >= 'X'

Raises the exception:
ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here

If you use an inline view (sub-query) then you can use the analytic function in the SELECT clause in the inner-query and then filter in the outer-query:
SELECT dummy
FROM   (
  SELECT dummy,
         MAX(dummy) OVER(PARTITION BY dummy) AS max_dummy 
  FROM   DUAL
)
WHERE  max_dummy >= 'X'

Which outputs:



DUMMY




X



fiddle
